# How to print definition of a variable in python?

Tags: python, mask

MY CODE:

```
mask1 = (logs125 >= 0) & (logs125 <= 3) & (loudestonedge == 0) & (geocontained == 1)
```

(each of the variables mentioned above are arrays. and i use it in the following way:)

```
posxmask1.extend(posx[mask1])
```

(which takes the original array `posx` and selects values according to `mask1` and stores them in `posxmask1`)

MY QUESTION IS THIS:

I want to print the definition of `mask1` as my graph's title. I want my graph title to be labelled as `(logs125 >= 0) & (logs125 <= 3) & (loudestonedge == 0) & (geocontained == 1)`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by its definition? Do you mean "mask1" or the value assigned to it, or something else?

Comment: I want to print "(logs125 >= 0)&(logs125 <=3)&(loudestonedge==0)&(geocontained==1)" . which is how i define my variable.

Comment: Then put `print "(logs125 >= 0)&(logs125 <=3)&(loudestonedge==0)&(geocontained==1)"`

Comment: well, the idea is not to do that everytime i change my selection criteria. i want it to be automatically reflected in the graph title.

Comment: The mistake you're making is thinking that you're providing the *definition* of a variable. The problem with thinking of your code in these terms is that the word "definition" implies some sort of permanence and implies that `mask1` intrinsically equals your expression. However, that's untrue: your expression is simply that -- an expression -- and Python will not bother to remember it once you finish executing it, rendering the expression irretrievable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in reverse.

You can do the following (untested, but the idea should work this way):

```
def_m = "(logs125 >= 0)&(logs125 <=3)&(loudestonedge==0)&(geocontained==1)"
mask1 = eval(def_m)
print def_m
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if `mask1` is defined in a different module, you could do it.

You'll need to use the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code) to get the source code of the file.
Then you would just loop the lines to find the line the variable is defined on, and extract the definition.

But, to be honest, I'm not sure if that's something worth doing. It could be more trouble than it's worth.